# Unable read file from partitioned directory

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I am unable to read file from partitioned directory in DBFS

But the other files are read easily in the normal scenarios
Am I missing something? Any alternative?
[Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqMxv.png)

Screengrab for successful run
[Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NO4E.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the path in the failed scenario to `/dbfs/<path>` instead of `dbfs:/`